# Matplotlib error in importing

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using OSX El Capitan and trying to import matplotlib.pyplot

when I do that I get recursive error and at the end it says "ValueError: insecure string pickle"

Here is the whole log:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 stats = Statistics("HumanData.xlsx")
>         5 
>   ----> 6 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')
>         7 
>         8 #matplotlib.pyplot.hist(stats.getActionData("Human", "Pacman", "Left"))
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc
>   in magic(self, arg_s)    2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s =
>   arg_s.partition(' ')    2335         magic_name =
>   magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
>   -> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)    2337     2338
>
> ## -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc
>   in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)    2255
>   kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals    2256
>   with self.builtin_trap:
>   -> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)    2258             return result    2259
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc
>   in matplotlib(self, line)
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc
>   in (f, *a, **k)
>       191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
>       192     def magic_deco(arg):
>   --> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
>       194 
>       195         if callable(arg):
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc
>   in matplotlib(self, line)
>        98             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
>        99         else:
>   --> 100             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
>       101             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
>       102
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc
>   in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)    3130                 gui, backend =
>   pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)    3131 
>   -> 3132         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)    3133         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)    3134
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc
>   in activate_matplotlib(backend)
>       272     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
>       273 
>   --> 274     import matplotlib.pyplot
>       275     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
>       276
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py
>   in ()
>        27 from cycler import cycler
>        28 import matplotlib
>   ---> 29 import matplotlib.colorbar
>        30 from matplotlib import style
>        31 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py
>   in ()
>        32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
>        33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
>   ---> 34 import matplotlib.collections as collections
>        35 import matplotlib.colors as colors
>        36 import matplotlib.contour as contour
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py
>   in ()
>        25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
>        26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
>   ---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
>        28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
>        29 from matplotlib import _path
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py
>   in ()
>        60 
>        61 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
>   ---> 62 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
>        63 from matplotlib.path import Path
>        64 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation, warn_deprecated
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py
>   in ()
>        13 from matplotlib.path import Path
>        14 from matplotlib import rcParams
>   ---> 15 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
>        16 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
>        17 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py
>   in ()    1418                 verbose.report("Using
>   fontManager instance from %s" % _fmcache)    1419         except:
>   -> 1420             _rebuild()    1421     else:    1422         _rebuild()
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py
>   in _rebuild()    1403     def _rebuild():    1404         global
>   fontManager
>   -> 1405         fontManager = FontManager()    1406         if _fmcache:    1407             pickle_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py
>   in **init**(self, size, weight)    1041         #  Load TrueType fonts
>   and create font dictionary.    1042 
>   -> 1043         self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()    1044         self.defaultFamily = {    1045
>   'ttf': 'Bitstream Vera Sans',
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py
>   in findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
>       321                     fontfiles[f] = 1
>       322 
>   --> 323             for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
>       324                 fontfiles[f] = 1
>       325
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py
>   in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext)
>       273         pipe = subprocess.Popen(['fc-list', '--format=%{file}\n'],
>       274                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>   --> 275                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>       276         output = pipe.communicate()[0]
>       277     except (OSError, IOError):
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in
>   **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines,
>   startupinfo, creationflags)
>       708                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
>       709                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>   --> 710                                 errread, errwrite)
>       711         except Exception:
>       712             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in
>   _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close,
>   p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)    1332
>   if e.errno != errno.ECHILD:    1333                         raise
>   -> 1334                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)    1335                 raise child_exception    1336
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in loads(str)
>   1386 def loads(str):    1387     file = StringIO(str)
>   -> 1388     return Unpickler(file).load()    1389     1390 # Doctest
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
>       862             while 1:
>       863                 key = read(1)
>   --> 864                 dispatchkey
>       865         except _Stop, stopinst:
>       866             return stopinst.value
>
> /Users/AhmedKhalifa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in
>   load_string(self)
>       970             if rep.startswith(q):
>       971                 if len(rep) < 2 or not rep.endswith(q):
>   --> 972                     raise ValueError, "insecure string pickle"
>       973                 rep = rep[len(q):-len(q)]
>       974                 break
>
> ValueError: insecure string pickle

Any help with that?

Comment: how did you install matplotlib?

Comment: using conda :) and tried also pip

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I'm not sure what the issue is but every once in a while, when trying to import matplotlib inside ipython I encounter this error and restarting the computer solves the issue. Maybe that would help in locating the issue?